# Date and Time Formatting in c#

Tags: c#

```
          int MM;
          int DD;
          int YYYY;
          switch(MM)
          {
                case 1:
                   DD = 31;
                   break;
                case 2:
                   DD = 28;
                   LDD = 29;
                   break;
                case 3:
                   DD = 31;
                   break;
                case 4:
                   DD = 30;
                   break;
                case 5:
                   DD = 31;
                   break;
                case 6:
                   DD = 30;
                   break;
                case 7:
                   DD = 31;
                   break;
                case 8:
                   DD = 31;
                   break;
                case 9:
                   DD = 30;
                   break;
                case 10:
                   DD = 31;
                   break;
                case 11:
                   days = 30;
                   break;
                case 12:
                   DD = 31;
                   break;
                default:
                   {
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid option");
                   }
        }
        if(Date == MM/DD/YYYY)
        string Date = Console.ReadLine();
```

I am trying to write a code that would accept the date as string and only in this format mm/dd/yyyy and the time has to accepted only in this format 10:00AM
By using DateTime i am getting the time in this format 10:00:00, the hour,minute,second format which i don't want.

I dont want to use try catch, exception.

Comment: Why not just use `DateTime.ParsExact()` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx?

Comment: Just for your information, there is a method [DateTime.DaysInMonth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx) that returns the number of days in a month... But as some other persons told you, you won't need it.

Answer (score 5):

Use DateTime.ParseExact and write your format string following these guidlines:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.ParseExact method and write your format definition in its second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx), this will check if the string is in the format you want, and return false if it isn't, and return true and populate your date if it is.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with `DateTime.TryParseExact`, as this method doesn't throws an exception for invalid dates:

```
DateTime parsed;
var input = "08/03/2013 08:30AM";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsed))
    Console.WriteLine("ok");
else
    Console.WriteLine("not ok");
```

Comment: Cant i just avoid the time and instead use only the date